# Create string column that goes up a value, everytime the condition is met

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following series

```
s = pd.Series({'01','02','03,'01','02','03','01','02','03'})
```

And the following list

```
l = ['A','B','C']
```

What I want to do is every time we reach the 01 string value, I advance one value in my list index and start filling up the apply result with the 'B' value.

```
s = pd.Series({'A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'})
```

I know i should use apply but i am having trouble formating the condition

```
s.apply(increment)

def increment(s):
   l = ['A','B','C']
   count = 0
   if s == '01':
     count += 1
     # Something wenting array here
     return l[count]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
out = pd.Series([np.nan]*len(s))
out.loc[s.loc[s=='01'].index] = l
out = out.ffill()
```

print(out):

```
0    A
1    A
2    A
3    B
4    B
5    B
6    C
7    C
8    C
```

Explanation:

- Initialize a series of `NaN` with length equal to original series
- Locate index in original series `s` where value is `01` and populate those locations with those from your list `l = [A, B, C]`
- Then ffill

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to achieve this:

**Option 1**

1. Convert `pd.Series` to `float`.
2. Get [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) and apply [`ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) to determine the breakpoints between the consecutive sequences.
3. Apply [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), but starting at `0` (with [`sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html)). At this stage, we will have a `pd.Series` with values as `[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]`.
4. Finally, we convert `lst` to a `dict`, with the indices as keys, so that we can apply [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html).

We can put this is a one-liner:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['01','02','03','01','02','03','01','02','03'])
lst = ['A','B','C']

result = (s.astype(float).diff().ne(1)).cumsum().sub(1)\
    .map({k: v for k, v in enumerate(lst)})
                                                  
print(result)

0    A
1    A
2    A
3    B
4    B
5    B
6    C
7    C
8    C
```

---

**Option 2**

1. Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) with [`groups`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.groups.html) to find all the indices ("labels") for value `01`.
2. Next, turn `lst` into `pd.Series` with found indices as `index` and feed this to a map apply to a `pd.Series` with `s.index`. This will get us "A" at 0, "B" at 3, "C" at 6.
3. Finally, apply [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html).

```
# Int64Index([0, 3, 6], dtype='int64')
indices_one = s.groupby(s).groups['01']

result2 = pd.Series(s.index).map(pd.Series(lst, index=indices_one)).ffill()

result2.equals(result)
# True
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is  a simple approach using apply

```py
s = pd.Series(['01','02','03','01','02','03','01','02','03'])

l = ['A','B','C']

def return_val(s):
    global l
    val = l[0]
    if s == '03':
        l = l[1:]
    return val

s.apply(return_val)
```

output:

```
0    A
1    A
2    A
3    B
4    B
5    B
6    C
7    C
8    C
dtype: object
```

If you want to avoid using globals you might use reduce and partial from functools, although this approach might not be that clear:

```py
from functools import reduce, partial

def return_val(prev_val, s, where_to_add: list):
    l = ["",'A','B','C']
    if s == '01':
        where = l.index(prev_val)
        prev_val = l[where+1]
    where_to_add.append(prev_val)
    return prev_val

my_list = []
return_val_partial = partial(return_val, where_to_add=my_list)
reduce(return_val_partial , s.values, "")
result = pd.Series(my_list)
print(result)
```